# How to backup MAAS 1.5.4 before upgrading to 1.7.1

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

I am planning to Upgrade to 1.7.1 from 1.5.4 MAAS.

Before I do that I want to make sure I have a restore plan. 
How do I back up MAAS 1.5.4 in case I want to revert back?

- Current version: 1.5.4.
- New version: 1.7.1 (latest stable)

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you need to backup the **MAAS** database (postgres), bits in `/etc/maas/` as well as any custom templates or other changes you might have made in `/var/lib/maas/`.

Sorry to be so vague, I did this upgrade a long time ago :)